# How would I go about debugging a cron job that executes the script, but the script seem to not complete?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, scheduling, scrapy

I have a cron job `scrape.sh` that look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch rage
cd /etc/myproject/scraper
scrapy crawl foosite --set FEED_URI=../feeds/foosite.xml --set FEED_FORMAT=xml
scrapy crawl barsite --set FEED_URI=../feeds/barsite.xml --set FEED_FORMAT=xml
```

When it executes the file rage does get created and judging from my syslog it does run as root, so permissions shouldn't be a problem.

```
May  6 17:35:01 server CRON[10233]: (root) CMD (/etc/myproject/scraper/scrape.sh)
May  6 17:40:01 server CRON[17804]: (root) CMD (/etc/myproject/scraper/scrape.sh)
```

When I run `scrape.sh` it executes as expected and puts the `foosite.xml` file in the `../feeds` directory, the directory exist and is empty when the cron jobs starts. What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Is it possible that the `scrapy` command is not found in the search path? Maybe it will work if you use the full path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If I were going to guess the problem
   it was an environment issue (e.g.
   scrapy is not in the path).
2. To debug, make sure your cron job is sending the standard out and standard error to a log file/and or syslog

Comment: Weirdly redirecting cron output to a log didn't show anything (I was using `&>`), but fixing the path issue solved it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the command scrapy is not found? Cron jobs typically get a different shell environment than interactive shells, so perhaps scrapy is missing in your PATH and you should use /some/full/path/to/scrapy.

If that doesn't help, try redirecting stdout and stderr to some files, so you can see what the output is?

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html